# Столкнулся с проблемой обновления progressbar в Qt на python (pyside2)

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

Пишу плеер, и возник вопрос, когда я запускаю песню, Я хочу чтобы progressbar обновлялся в то время когда идет музыка, сделал цикл, закинул его в трэд, значения на обновление передаются через сигнал в qml, но в чем проблема, эти значения передаются только тогда когда я нажимаю на эту кнопку, но никак не в реальном времени. То есть я нажимаю на кнопку и срабатывает цикл который передаёт значения в progressBar. Я любитель Qt, так что не судите строго)

Main.py

```
progressMusicSignal = Signal(float, arguments=['progressMusic'])

@Slot('float')
def setValue(self, flagTrue):
    global thread, que
    if flagTrue == 1:
        que = queue.Queue()
        thread = Thread(target=lambda ques, arg1: ques.put(progressBarMusic(arg1)), args=(que, flagTrue),
                                daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        result = que.get()
        self.progressMusicSignal.emit(result)
    elif flagTrue == 2:
        thread.join()

def playMusic(flagMusic=0):
    if flagMusic == 1:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(PATHLESS + MUSICFILEWAV)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    if flagMusic == 2:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    if flagMusic == 3:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

def progressBarMusic(flagTrue):
    if flagTrue == 1:
        while True:
            song = pygame.mixer.Sound(PATHLESS + MUSICFILEWAV)
            getLengthMusic = pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length(song)
            milSec = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
            operationLength = getLengthMusic // 10
            print(operationLength)
            sec = milSec // 1000
            secRes = milSec // 100
            print(secRes)
            operationSecPercent = (secRes / operationLength) / 100
            print(operationSecPercent)
            if sec != getLengthMusic:
                return operationSecPercent
```

Main.qml

```
RoundButton {
    id: plauPauseBtn
    x: 370
    y: 15
    width: 50
    height: 50
    text: "\u25b7"
    enabled: true
    opacity: 1.0
    font.weight: Font.ExtraBold
    font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
    font.strikeout: false
    font.underline: false
    font.italic: false
    display: AbstractButton.TextBesideIcon
    font.bold: false
    font.pointSize: 14
    font.family: "Tahoma"
    onClicked: {
        plauPauseBtn.opacity = 0.0;
        plauPauseBtn.enabled = false;
        stopPauseBtn.opacity = 1.0;
        stopPauseBtn.enabled = true;
        con.playMusicInt(1)
        con.setValue(1)
    }
}

RoundButton {
    id: stopPauseBtn
    x: 370
    y: 15
    width: 50
    height: 50
    text: "||"
    enabled: false
    opacity: 0.0
    bottomPadding: 13
    font.weight: Font.ExtraBold
    font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
    font.strikeout: false
    font.underline: false
    font.italic: false
    display: AbstractButton.TextBesideIcon
    font.bold: false
    font.pointSize: 7
    font.family: "Tahoma"
    onClicked: {
        con.playMusicInt(2)
        con.setValue(2)
        stopPauseBtn.opacity = 0.0;
        stopPauseBtn.enabled = false;
        playAgainBtn.opacity = 1.0;
        playAgainBtn.enabled = true;
    }
}

    RoundButton {
        id: playAgainBtn
        x: 370
        y: 15
        width: 50
        height: 50
        text: "\u25b7"
        enabled: false
        opacity: 0.0
        bottomPadding: 13
        font.weight: Font.ExtraBold
        font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
        font.strikeout: false
        font.underline: false
        font.italic: false
        display: AbstractButton.TextBesideIcon
        font.bold: false
        font.pointSize: 14
        font.family: "Tahoma"
        onClicked: {
            con.playMusicInt(3)
            con.setValue(1)
            playAgainBtn.opacity = 0.0;
            playAgainBtn.enabled = false;
            stopPauseBtn.opacity = 1.0;
            stopPauseBtn.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    ProgressBar {
        id: musicProgressBar
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 800
        height: 5
        indeterminate: false
        value: 0.0
    }
        Connections {
            target: con
            onProgressMusicSignal: {
                musicProgressBar.value = progressMusic
        }
    }
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример, который демонстрирует вашу проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick проблема в том что я хочу чтобы значения в progressbar передавались сразу, а не только по нажатию кнопки.